# ZOO Component - Image Database

Tags: joomla-2.5, zoo-cck

I'm displaying images on my website with the ZOO component and with the help of the movie database, users can rate the image (or the video).

When users are on the main page of the section they just see the image, and have to click on it to see the rest (rating, text ..), but I want to show users the ratings of each pictures on the main page.

Is there an option I didn't see in the ZOO component?

1/2 : The main page
[image]
2/2 : The image page.
[image]

So I want the rating to be presents on the main page, under the pictures.

---

Backend:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had to change the Default/Teaser template settings , and add Ratings [image: ratings].
Now we can see the ratings above pictures directly from the main page :

[image: RATINGS]